# Show that $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor$ is $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $n^2$ be the largest perfect square that is less than or equal to $x$, then $x$ can be defined as follows,

$$ x = n^2 + m + \epsilon, 0\lt\epsilon\lt 1, m\in\Bbb Z$$

Show that $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor$ is $n$ and show that $\left\lfloor \sqrt{\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor} \right\rfloor$ is also $n$.

Proof: let us just consider proofing why $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor$ is $n$.

Start with $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor$,

$$\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{n^2 + m + \epsilon}$$

The proof claims that since $n^2$ is the perfect largest square that is less than or equal to $x$, $\sqrt{x}$ has to be between $n$ and $n+1$,

$$\left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor = n$$

Could you please explain as why $\left\lfloor \sqrt{x} \right\rfloor = n$?

Comment: By "between", they meant $n \le \sqrt x < n+1$, where $n$ is a positive integer (hopefully). Now what could $\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor$ be?

Comment: @player3236, why you included $n$? It should not be inclusive on both sides. That is how I translated it. An integer n between $x$ and $y$ (where $x≤y$) is an integer $n$ with $x<n $and $n<y$.

Comment: @Avra Well, $n < \sqrt x < n+1$ implies $n\le \sqrt x < n+1$, which implies $\lfloor \sqrt x \rfloor = n$.

Comment: @Avra your question defines $n^2$ to be "the largest perfect square that is less than or equal to $x$", then equality has to be present on one side: $0\le \epsilon<1$ and $n \le \sqrt x < n+1$.

Comment: @peterwhy, Thank you, but the proof does only state that $0\lt \epsilon \lt 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specification, you overlooked something:

Since $n^2 \leq x < (n+1)^2$, 
$m \leq (2n)$.

This follows, since if $m \geq (2n+1)$, then $n^2 + m + \epsilon$ would be $\geq (n+1)^2$, which is a contradiction.

Then, you have that $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{n^2 + m + \epsilon} < \sqrt{n^2 + (2n+1)} = \sqrt{(n+1)^2} = (n+1)\implies$ 
$n = \sqrt{n^2} \leq \sqrt{x} < (n+1) \implies$ 
$\left\lfloor \sqrt{x}\right\rfloor = n.$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see why $m$ is there in the proof? The usage of $\epsilon$ is understood, however. How you defined $m$ to be $\le (2n)$?

Comment: @Avra Tricky question.  In a case like this, the mathSE protocol is to try to indicate where the OP *went wrong*, rather than proving the assertion *from scratch*.  Your analysis began: Let $n^2$ be the largest perfect square that is less than or equal to $x$, then $x$ can be defined as follows,

$$ x = n^2 + m + \epsilon, 0\lt\epsilon\lt 1, m\in\Bbb Z$$  Therefore, I used your analysis as a **starting point** to indicate where you went wrong.  You overlooked that $m$ has an upper bound of $(2n)$.

Comment: @Avra In my answer, I determined that if $m \geq (2n+1)$ then $x \geq (n+1)^2$, which is a contradiction, based on **your assumption** that $(n^2)$ is the largest perfect square $\leq x$.  Therefore, since $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $m < (2n+1), ~m \leq (2n).$